# When I increase the textcontent value the decrease button is still disabled

Tags: javascript, dom

Well I cant enable the decrease button when the textcontent value is higher than 1. My goal is to increase the value from 1 to all the way up with enabling the decrease button but when i decrease down to 1 i want my decrease button to be disabled.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
var increaseButton = document.createElement('button')
var decreaseButton = document.createElement('button')

newDiv.textContent = 1
document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
document.body.appendChild(increaseButton)
document.body.appendChild(decreaseButton)


increaseButton.setAttribute('id', 'increase')
decreaseButton.setAttribute('id', 'decrease')

if(Number(newDiv.textContent) == 1) {
    decreaseButton.setAttribute('disabled', '')
}else {
    increaseButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
}

increaseButton.onclick = () => {
    newDiv.textContent = Number(newDiv.textContent) + 1
}

decreaseButton.onclick = () => {
    newDiv.textContent = Number(newDiv.textContent) - 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/mLq5aknx/

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
var increaseButton = document.createElement('button')
var decreaseButton = document.createElement('button')

newDiv.textContent = 1
document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
document.body.appendChild(increaseButton)
document.body.appendChild(decreaseButton)


increaseButton.setAttribute('id', 'increase')
decreaseButton.setAttribute('id', 'decrease')

function checkAndDisable() {
  if(Number(newDiv.textContent) == 1) {
    decreaseButton.setAttribute('disabled', '')
  }else {
     decreaseButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }
}

checkAndDisable();

increaseButton.onclick = () => {
    newDiv.textContent = Number(newDiv.textContent) + 1;
    checkAndDisable();
}

decreaseButton.onclick = () => {
    newDiv.textContent = Number(newDiv.textContent) - 1;
    checkAndDisable();
}
```

You need to make sure you call the function that checks if it should be disabled when the value changes. Also, you mistakenly wrote `increaseButton.removeAttribute('disabled')`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting the *disabled* property outside of the click event handler functions, there is no effect on the code when you click the buttons. You should set the *disabled* property inside the click handler functions:

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
var increaseButton = document.createElement('button');
increaseButton.textContent = 'Increase';
var decreaseButton = document.createElement('button');
decreaseButton.textContent = 'Decrease';

newDiv.textContent = 1;
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
document.body.appendChild(increaseButton);
document.body.appendChild(decreaseButton);


increaseButton.setAttribute('id', 'increase');
decreaseButton.setAttribute('id', 'decrease');

decreaseButton.setAttribute('disabled',true);
increaseButton.onclick = () => {
  newDiv.textContent = Number(newDiv.textContent) + 1;
  enableDisable();
}

decreaseButton.onclick = () => {
    newDiv.textContent = Number(newDiv.textContent) - 1;
    enableDisable();
}

function enableDisable(){
  if(Number(newDiv.textContent) == 1) {
    decreaseButton.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  }else {
    decreaseButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) who listens to changes in your created DIV.

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
var increaseButton = document.createElement('button');
var decreaseButton = document.createElement('button');
var observerOptions = { childList: true }; //Needed observer options

newDiv.textContent = 1;
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
document.body.appendChild(increaseButton);
document.body.appendChild(decreaseButton);

increaseButton.setAttribute('id', 'increase')
decreaseButton.setAttribute('id', 'decrease')

// Create an observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (Number(newDiv.textContent) == 1) {
      decreaseButton.setAttribute('disabled', '')
    } else {
      decreaseButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
    }
  });
});
//Start observer
observer.observe(newDiv, observerOptions);

increaseButton.onclick = () => {
  newDiv.textContent = Number(newDiv.textContent) + 1
}

decreaseButton.onclick = () => {
  newDiv.textContent = Number(newDiv.textContent) - 1
}
```

But in your case a simple function is the easiest way. ;-)